# Gstreamer screenshot from RTSP stream is always gray

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to create screenshot (i.e. grab one frame) from RTSP camera stream using gstreamer pipeline.

The pipeline used looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=$CAM_URL is_live=true ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! jpegenc snapshot=true ! filesink location=/tmp/frame.jpg
```

Problem is that the result image is always gray, with random artifacts. It looks like it's grabbing the very first frame, and it doesn't wait for the key frame.

Is there any way how can I modify the pipeline to actually grab first valid frame of video? Or just wait long enough to be sure that there was at least one key frame already?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why, but after some trial and error it is now working with `decodebin3` instead of `decodebin`. Documentation is still bit discouraging though, stating *decodebin3 is still experimental API and a technology preview. Its behaviour and exposed API is subject to change.*

Full pipeline looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=$CAM_URL is_live=true ! decodebin3 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc snapshot=true ! filesink location=/tmp/frame.jpg
```